# v4l2loopback /dev/video2 Not being created

Tags: v4l2loopback

Running: Arch Linux, using package "[v4l2loopback-dkms](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/v4l2loopback-dkms/)"

Software I'm trying to get running:
https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam

This software uses v4l2loopback, which I've setup a few times successfully.

I have two files to load v4l2loopback on boot, with these contents:

The first file simply loads the module on boot.

```
/etc/modules-load.d/v4l2loopback.conf
```

Contents: `v4l2loopback`

This second file creates a dummy output device at /dev/video2

```
/etc/modprobe.d/linux-fake-background.conf
```

Contents: `options v4l2loopback devices=1 exclusive_caps=1 video_nr=2 card_label="fake-cam"`

However, I do not have a /dev/video2 which these files should create. The "video_nr=2" is what should make it map directly to /dev/video2

The module is loaded, trying to unload it results in this error:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback is in use.
```

However, if I try to manually create a video output, it just simply hangs for hours with seemingly no progress or errors:

```
$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 exclusive_caps=1 video_nr=2 card_label="fake-cam"
Nothing happens, and I've let it sit there for over 60 minutes
```

I've been reading the README, they state that `/sys/devices/virtual/video4linux` should contain a list of the devices, but I don't even have the video4linux folder. I've tried reinstalling the v4l2loopback package to no avail.

I also already have my linux-headers installed.

I have tried rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing a kernel update to 5.18.2, everything was suddenly working. I'm assuming it was something with that version.